# Get DIV element by ID or Class as href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following structure

JAVASCRIPT

```
//ID of container
$('a#modal_info').attr('rel','{handler: "iframe", size: {x: '+(width-(width*0.03))+', y: '+(height-(height*0.20))+'}}');
});

</script>
```

HTML

```
<!-- Esta parte é o Link para fazer a chamada -->

<div id="modal_info" class="modal barradofundo" onclick="window.location.href = this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;">

<a href="/va/artigos-complexos/banners-cursos.html" id="modal_info" class="modal catalogobotao2">SAIBA +</a>

</div>
```

What am I trying to achieve here: The `href` element that uses the id `modal_info` is called by the javascript and opens a popup. I can't reproduce it here because it's a Joomla website, but it works. I need to achieve the same result with the div that uses the class `barradofundo`, as it is already clickable. How is it clickable? Because of the part `onclick="window.location.href = this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;"`

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate IDs. Whatever you do with them might fail.

Comment: The `href` element that uses the id `modal_info` is called by the javascript and opens a popup. I can't reproduce it here because it's a Joomla website, but it works. I need to achieve the same result with the div that uses the class `barradofundo`, as it is already clickable. How is it clickable? Because of the part `onclick="window.location.href = this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;"`